# Laravel Nova hide creating button from resource's relationship

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-nova

I have a 2 Laravel Nova resources, Customer and Debt. Debt belongsTo customer and Customer hasMany Debts.

Now, when I open some Customer, there is list of his Debts according to hasMany relationship, but up there is "create debt" button. I dont want to be able to create debts via customer resource, I want to be able to create debts only when I am on Debt resource.

I googled a lot, but i didnt find a solution, sorry if this is simple question. I found only how i can disable adding debt at all, but i want to disable creating them only on customer detail.

Thanks a lot good people!

Answer (score 1):

The following solutions should help you:

https://nova.laravel.com/docs/2.0/resources/relationships.html#belongsto

> ```
> BelongsTo::make('User')->hideCreateRelationButton();
> BelongsTo::make('User')->showCreateRelationButton(false);
> BelongsTo::make('User')->showCreateRelationButton(function (NovaRequest $request) {
>     return Str::contains($request->getUri(), 'authors');
> });
> ```